# Чек с безналичной оплатой Штрих

Tags: касса, ккт

Вопрос интеграции со встраиваемым оборудованием

Отправляю на кассу товар 'тест ' количество 1 цена 1:

`024a ff46 01000000 01 e80300000000 6400000000 ffffffffff ffffffffff 00 00 01 04 f2e5f1f22000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 4d`

ответ кассы - ок:
`ff46 00`

Закрываю безналичной оплатой
`0249 85 01000000 0000000000 6400000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 a9`

ответ кассы "Закрытие чека: Вносимая безналичной оплатой сумма больше суммы чека"
`85 4d`

Помогите разобраться.

Comment: количество надо умножить на 1000000

Comment: а разве для кассы нет вменяемого API, чтобы не нужно было отправлять бессмысленный набор байт?

Comment: У штриха нет ничего внятного. Есть старое брошенное - его и довожу до удовлетворения нуждам)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В штрихе количество в 1000000 долях. Нужно умножить чтоб получить целые штуки.